# Can't access css file, htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I've added a .htaccess file to redirect some of the requests, for example:
`/home/index` becomes `/index.php?controller=home&action=index&params=`, but that .htaccess file prevents me to access /content/styles.css file too. For some reason I can access `/content/images/default.png`.

Htaccess contents:

```
Options +Indexes
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.[^\/]+)\/(.[^\/]+)\/(.+)\/*$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&params=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.[^\/]+)\/*$ index.php?controller=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.[^\/]+)\/(.[^\/]+)\/*$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [QSA,L]
```

And it's located in public_html directory.

I've tried to add another .htaccess with `Options +Indexes` to `/content/` directory, but no change. Accessing any file from `/content/` but no `/content/images/` is prevented.

This: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/styles.css" />` - doesn't work.
This: `mysite.com/content/styles.css` - doesn't work.
This: `mysite.com/content/images/default.png` - works.

//Edit:

When I move `/content/styles.css` to `/content/styles/styles.css` is works well, but is there something wrong with this config?

Answer (score 1):

Add this tag in pages where you want to access `css` and `png` files.

```
<base href="http://www.yourdomain.com/" />
```

And then try to access that page.

Comment: That haven't worked for me, I have put that line in both `index.php` in public_html and in  `layout.php'  which contains html for all pages. It might be some weird .htaccess config in other file (site is hosted by a company), although I didn't find one.